# linux timer and virtualized servers : how to read the timer frequency?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

On our servers we look for sustained bandwidth, but in the last years  many distro staterd to ship with kernel biased for desktop users and low latency.

As explained in this FAQ [Linux guests may cause a high CPU load](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html#idm10288),
valid also for other hypervisor :

1. These guests kernels have timer frequency = 1000 Hz. Disruptive for servers running into a VM.
2. The common cure is 'kernel parameter : divider=10'

Question : is there a reliable method to grasp the current timer frequency ?

Notes :

1. I have to code the test into a script ... bash or python.
2. I feel the euristic 'cat /proc/interrupts; sleep 10; cat /proc/interrupts'
   isn't reliable, but you can convince me.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the lines starting with *CONFIG_HZ=* into these files :

> /boot/config-$(uname -r)
>
> /boot/config
>
> /proc/config.gz

Note : if the last file is missing, try to load it with

> modprobe configs

Last chance : google for the tool *extract-ikconfig* (sorry I didn't try it).